# Existe alguma maneria de voltar para o último branch no Git?

Tags: git

O título diz tudo. Volta e meia usamos o Git da seguinte forma:

```
git checkout branch_x
git checkout branch_y
git checkout branch_x
```

`x` pode ser `master`, ou algum *feature branch* qualquer.

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de voltar para o último *branch* utilizado.
O Git possui algo equivalente ao `cd -` para diretórios na linha de comando?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creio que basta fazer o seguinte na linha de comandos:

```
git checkout @{-1}
```

Tal com está exemplificado nestas [respostas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206801/is-there-any-way-to-git-checkout-previous-branch).

Comment: Opa, pela [outra resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33199051/664577) nesse mesmo link descobri que `git checkout -` também funciona em versões relativamente modernas do Git. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Se quer alternar apenas entre dois branches (mudei para o branch A, depois para o B, volta para A, volta para B, etc), então basta usar `git checkout -` (ou, a partir do Git 2.23.0, o comando equivalente `git switch -`).

Desde a versão 1.6.2, [usar o hífen desta forma é equivalente ao `@{-1}`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.6.2.txt#L85) que foi sugerido na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98507/112052).

---

E para completar, a sintaxe `@{-N}` serve para pegar o N-ésimo branch anterior em que você estava (e não importa se você mudou de branch com [`checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-ltbranchgt) ou [`switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt-ltstart-pointgt), o histórico é "compartilhado" entre eles).

Lembrando que quando há vários branches envolvidos, este histórico pode ficar confuso. Por exemplo, supondo que estou atualmente no branch `master` e mudo de branch algumas vezes:

```bash
# estou no "master"
$ git status
On branch master

# mudo para o branch "a"
$ git checkout a # ou "git switch a" para Git >= 2.23.0

# depois para o "b"
$ git checkout b # ou "git switch b" para Git >= 2.23.0

# e depois para o "c"
$ git checkout c # ou "git switch c" para Git >= 2.23.0
```

Neste caso, `@{-1}` equivale ao branch "b", `@{-2}` ao branch "a" e `@{-3}` ao branch "master".

E se eu mudar novamente para o `master` (ou seja, `git checkout master`, ou  `git switch master` para Git >= 2.23.0), agora `@{-1}` passou a ser o branch "c", `@{-2}` é branch "b" e `@{-3}` é o branch "a" (e `@{-4}` é o próprio `master`, que é onde eu estava há 4 checkouts atrás).

---

Mas se estiver alternando entre dois branches, então `@{-1}` ou apenas `-` é o suficiente.